# Wordpress strategy for having a modular front page

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm building a WP theme from scratch and what I want is having a front page displaying several parts that I want to style individually. Like this for example: https://www.welikesmall.com/studio/ (I need something more simple but that gives you an idea). There is almost no single block of content that is styled the same.

In a WP static page, at some point, you are going to end up with `the_content()` that will get the single piece of content of your static page. If you've used, for ex, groups in Gutengerg, you are going to have something like this:

```
<main>
<article>
<div class="entry-content">

>>> All your content here divided with <div class="wp-block-group">
```

And that's all. It seems there is no way to add classes to each group, or any part of what is within the '''entry-content''' class. So there is no way you can have a static page where you can target specific elements with ids or classes.

What I need is more like:

```
<main>
<article>
<div class="entry-content">
<div class="wp-block-group group-about">...</div>
<div class="wp-block-group group-image-full">...</div>
<div class="video-full">...</div>
....
```

What would be the best way you think?

1. Just make a front page with my own html, without using Gutenberg (will not be editable via the block editor later though, which is a problem, no more content management).
2. Inserting classes directly in the block editor? (easiest but best way to forget about it...)
3. Do some query to the DB to add the different parts of the page? Like piling up posts on the page?
4. Making a plugin to add my own custom Gutenberg blocks, with my own classes/ids...?
5. Building a front-end with something else (Vuejs...) and just using the WP REST API?
6. Anything else?

Personnaly, I think 4 is the best way but I may be wrong. And the learning curve is quite steep for me (trying now). If someone more experienced can help, that would be really nice.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would suggest you to post this question on WPSE https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you Rahil, I didn't know, I'm going to post it there instead yes.